# DOM keydown event with a long key press

Tags: html, dom, w3c

I want to be notified when a key is pressed down, and then not notified until it is released. Is this possible?

When the key is held down, listening for `keydown` appears to repeatedly trigger the `onkeydown` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a flag, and reset on key up.

```js
let isPressed = false;

document.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  if (!isPressed) {
    isPressed = true;
    onDown();
  }
})

document.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  isPressed = false;
  console.log('Up.')
})

function onDown() {
  console.log('Pressed')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you have a keydown function where you have a mapping between a key and whether it's already pressed down.  Look at the mapping to see if it's already pressed.

In the keyup, you'll remove the key from the mapping.